# Django: dollar symbol in urls.py

Tags: django, django-urls, symbols, dollar-sign

Wondering if it is possible to catch dollar symbol in urls.py. 
Url is called as "/blabla/bla/$something" and I'm having hard time trying to catch this url, as "$" is being interpreted as end of line. Can someone please assist.

Thanks.

Comment: Forgot to mention, it is django 1.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way of escaping special characters in regular expressions is to prefix them with "\".

So try something like this:

```
url('^/blabla/bla/\$omething/$', …)
```

Comment: Apparently it does work. I just wasn't calling the link properly from shell in the first place. I was calling it with no escaping in bash through curl which was translating $something at the end into bash empty var...